# Win32 Finding active popup window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am having an issue with trying to receive a callback when switching to a popup window that gets created in a new thread within a Maya plugin. I spawn the new thread, then create a window, like so:

```cpp
hWnd = CreateWindow(
    "Sample", "Sample", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Then I have what seems like it should be a pretty straightforward window procdure to determine if the created window has gotten a foreground event:

```cpp
windowsEventHook = SetWinEventHook(
    EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, // Range of events (4 to 5).
    NULL, // Handle to DLL.
    selectMayaObjectOnActiveWindowCallback, // The callback.
    0, 0, // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
    WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
```

This procedure runs as expected whenever a window is selected via the thumbnail:

```cpp
void CALLBACK selectMayaObjectOnActiveWindowCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject, LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
```

The issue, however, is that `idObject`, `idChild`, and `dwEventThread` are the same if I click on the original thumbnail window containing Maya, or the Thumbnail containing the window I have created.

In addition, I am able to find the created window by title, but when comparing it to the `HWND` instance that is passed in, they are not the same when clicking on my window.

I have tried limiting the callback to my process ID by passing in the process ID via `GetCurrentThreadId()`, as well as compare them using the title. However, the title appears to be listed as `TaskListThumbnailWnd`.

I have also tried several variations of `getActiveWindow()`, `getForegroundWindow()`, `GetWindow(hwnd, GW_ENABLEDPOPUP)`, and `getFocus()`.

Is there a way I can directly set an `onClick` listener from an `HWND` instance, or determine if a popup window has been clicked?

Comment: The flags you pass to SetWinEventHook() are surely wrong, if the add-in is built as a DLL and loaded into the Maya process.  You shouldn't get any callback at all, TaskListThumbnailWnd belongs to Explorer.  Use WINEVENT_INCONTEXT.

Comment: hmmm no the plugin is built as an .mll.  Switching the flag to incontext I get no alert at all when switching between the two.

Comment: The file extension doesn't make a difference. This is still presumably a DLL, and you must pass that module's base address into `SetWinEventHook()`. You can store it from your `DllMain()` implementation, discover it using [`GetModuleHandleExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) with the `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` flag, or make use of the `__ImageBase` [linker pseudovariable](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483).